# How to make my cat understand that she is being scolded for doing a certain thing but not for staying at the current place

Tags: cats, behavior

When my cat is doing something which is prohibited, I look towards my cat and speak her name in deep loud voice. But my cat thinks that she is being scolded for being at that place and run away about 2 feet away. But what I actually want is that my cat should only stop doing what she is doing. Not run away from the place.

For example wifi antenna of wifi box is by the side of study table and my cat starts chewing on the antenna. When I scold her she thinks that she is being scolded for being on the side of study table and will move away. But what I actually want her is to stop chewing on the antenna.

So how to make my cat understand for what she is being scolded for?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cats do not respond well to negative reinforcement, and you may be doing the wrong thing by scolding her. I have not had this particular problem with my cat, but it may be worthwhile to gently remove the cable from her mouth when you see her chewing it, and not reprove her in any other way. Here is why I say this:

One particular problem with our cat (who is very well-behaved) is kneading, which can be uncomfortable if he is sitting on my lap. However, my (elderly) mother finds it very painful, and does not like it at all. She tried telling him off for doing it, but as you can guess, he just ran away. We managed to stop him doing it by gently lifting his paws from our laps, and not scolding him at all, but rather petting him. He quickly understood that he should not knead on our laps, and that his continued company was still desired.

Try to adapt this technique to your own situation. Gently stop her from chewing, and give her all the attention that she may desire. Of course, give her plenty of other things to chew.